# DrawerLayout not found in Android Maven project at runtime

Tags: java, android, maven

Okay, so I've been trying to figure out this problem for a few weeks now and been on StackOverflow profusely viewing similar problems and trying to apply them to my own situation to no avail. I am worried I am just doing something incredibly stupid or forgetting something stupid and will waste someone's time but I'm out of options and ideas at this point, so apologies if that ends up being the case. I'm not using Eclipse or Android Studio, just CLI Maven. I need to use the DrawerLayout in my app, but the app crashes when attempting to instantiate it due to not being able to find the class (and presumably the rest of the support-v4 package) at runtime. So, step by step.

Here's the line of code that creates the DrawerLayout:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = new android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout(this);
```

Here's the stack trace of how the app crashes when it tries to create a new instance of the DrawerLayout.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065): Process: com.patron.main, PID: 2065
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at com.patron.main.FlashMenu.onCreate(FlashMenu.java:120)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2065):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
W/ActivityManager( 1228):   Force finishing activity com.patron.main/.FlashMenu
```

Here's how I'm including the dependency in my POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
  <version>21.0.3</version>
  <type>aar</type>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I'm using the local maven repository provided by google in the android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository folder as suggested by another SO post. Obviously it can compile and run ok so I'm confident it's finding it properly. When I call mvn dependency:build-classpath to see the compile-time classpath, it shows me this:
[image: Classpath]

And then manually opening that AAR folder in 7zip and checking the classes jar to ensure the DrawerLayout is in there, I can see it most certainly is:
[image: DrawerLayout in Classpath]

So at this point I am unsure what I can change or do to get this support package available at runtime. I went over the classpath in detail and I am confident I am not importing the support-v4 package twice, just once, and judging by the nature of errors from importing it twice I don't think I'd be able to compile if that were the problem. I tried manually setting the scope of the dependency to compile (which should be the right one), then to runtime and provided just in case without any luck. If anyone has any ideas as to what the problem could be to solve this NoClassDefFoundError, it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For posterity:
You need to update to the latest version of the Android Maven Plugin, in order to avoid this error. In addition, an old bug I was running into where ActivityCompat21 was not being found along several other classes that I fixed with a hacky workaround is also fixed by updating to version 4.0.0-rc2 of the plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0-rc.2</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <includeLibsJarsFromAar>true</includeLibsJarsFromAar>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: How does your build path look like ? Did you have to add the external jar to the build path as well ?